# what -is the FAIL(1264, "Value out of range for column 'id' in row 1") error?

Tags: mysql, telegram

I wrote a telegram bot, the logic is that when you click on the start button, the user is added to the column "first_reg" tried it on many accounts, in the console I get FAIL(1264, "Value out of range for column 'id' in row 1") error.
I do not understand what the problem is

@connection_func def create_table(connection):

```
"""Создание таблицы в базе данных""" with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
    create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE users_id(id int," \
                         " first_name varchar(128)," 
                         " last_name varchar(128)," 
                         " user_name varchar(128)," 
                         " fist_reg varchar(128)," 
                         " last_use varchar(128)
                         , PRIMARY KEY (id));" 
cursor.execute(create_table_query)
```

Comment: Error is on id not first_reg  tell us the datatype of id and the value you are passing to it preferably including your code.

Comment: instaed of INT use BIGINT there big number will fir better, besides wouldn't it be better to use auto_INCREMENT on the id